# Unconditional branching and code coverage

Tags: branch, code-coverage, code-analysis, control-flow

So I have learned that branch coverage differs from decision coverage as branch coverage typically includes also unconditional branches, e.g. methods calls, using of throw, break and other keywords in C#.
But I wonder, is this kind of branch coverage actually used in code analyzers? I suspect they use decision coverage, making sure that all decision outcomes (i.e. resulting branches) are covered.
I mean, the following code has 2 conditional, but 5 unconditional branches:

```
if(A)
  B();
  C();
  D();
  E();
else
 X();
```

And I believe that if I write a test to evaluate A to just false, the code analyzers will tell me that the branch coverage is 50%. But from the unconditional branches perspective, more will nto be executed.
Is that correct?

Comment: That really depends on the analyzer.  dotCover will identify the lines of code hit by tests, which can therefore be used to determine if all possible lines of code will be executed.

Comment: @drz:  OP didn't ask about *line* coverage.  He asked about branch vs. decision coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch coverage doesn't tell you if a decision has been tested as both true and false.

Example:

```
 if (c) {
    x=...
 }
 y=...
```

If c evaluates to TRUE, the block containing x=... is executed, and
branch coverage will detect that.  It will also detect that the code starting at y has been executed.   So you'll get 100% coverage if C is true, without having any idea what happens if C is false.

With decision coverage, you would know that C has been evaluated and produces both TRUE and FALSE, if you had 100% coverage.

If your conditional if has a then block *and* an else block, then branch coverage and decision coverage will give you the same information.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. But then I have no idea why virtually all books (check on Google books) say that branch coverage is the same thing as decision coverage.

Comment: But I am not sure about the example - I think that if is actually a branching point and branch coverage does detect that the other branch was not run - from the control flow graph it is obvious.

Comment: Imagine I have a statement  bool z = ( i > j) ;   Arguably there are no branches.  (The x86 machine code for this is mov r1,i; cmp r1, j; setle r1; mov z, r1... no branches).   But there is clearly a decision.

Comment: Yes, I think that is why DO-178B considers decision coverage to be stronger. According to them, it should deals with boolean assignments as well. But most other definition do not accept that.

Comment: If decision coverage and branch coverage were the same, DO-178B couldn't consider one to be stronger than the other :-}  Yes, it is a matter of definition, but in general condition coverage >> decision coverage >> branch coverage.    There are like 150 definitions of "code coverage" of which these 3 tend to be the most common.  As a practical matter, people have a hard time hitting 80% with branch coverage.    Setting your sights low so you can achieve is probably not a bad place to start.